# Do I need to stop the stopwatch if the enclosing method is about to return?

Tags: c#-4.0, garbage-collection, stopwatch

Consider the following method:

```
DoTimeIntensiveOperation()
{
    var t = new Stopwatch();

    foreach(var element in a_very_long_array)
    {
        DoATimeConsumingTask(element);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Took me " + t.Elapsed);
    return;
}
```

Do I need to call `t.Stop()` before returning?

As far as I know, the garbage collector will destroy anything that doesn't have a reference chain going back to the main method. The only reference to the created `Stopwatch` is `t`, so when `DoTimeIntensiveOperation`, `t` will be freed and the `Stopwatch` should be eligible for destruction. But does the fact that it's still "ticking" interfere with the GC?

Comment: Also here: [Should I Stop Stopwatch at the end of the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140261/should-i-stop-stopwatch-at-the-end-of-the-method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, I threw this quick test and it seems that once the GC is run, the stopwatch is destroyed. (Feel free to correct the code)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      DoTimeIntensiveOperation();

      GC.Collect();
      while (swRef.IsAlive)
      {
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Destroyed");
 }

 static WeakReference swRef = null;
 static void DoTimeIntensiveOperation()
 {
     Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();
     swRef = new WeakReference(sw);
     return;
 }
```

The output is `Destroyed` when `GC.Collect` is called. Of course, in a real program you're unlikely to explicitly call `GC.Collect` but this is to show that the Stopwatch object is destroyed once out the scope of the method even if `Stop` hasn't been called.