# Should I Stop Stopwatch at the end of the method?

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

Let's imagine we have simple measurements using `Stopwatch`

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // some hard work
    Logger.Log("Time elapsed: {0}", timer.Elapsed);
    timer.Stop(); // Do I need to call this?
}
```

According to MSDN:

> In a typical Stopwatch scenario, you call the Start method, **then eventually call the Stop method**, and then you check elapsed time using the Elapsed property.

I'm not sure if I should call this method when I'm no longer interested with timer instance. Should I "clear up" using `Stop` method?

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that Logger.Log(..) costs nothing because `timer.Elapsed` is read **before** the logger logs.

Comment: The `Stop` method prevents you from careless mistakes, for example if you're evaluating the `Elapsed` property multiple times.

Comment: Take a look at the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs

Comment: Since the timer is going out of scope, why do you believe that calling `Stop` would do any difference? You can't use the value anyway

Comment: @default I think OP is concerned if keeping the stopwatch ON is resource consuming. Its not clear if a timer is running in a background thread.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

No, you don't need to stop it. [`Stop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop) just stops tracking elapsed time. It does not free up any resources.

Comment: But it is good practice to use it anyway to prevent careless mistakes.

Comment: It doesn't prevent anything, he's creating the stopwatch in the method and not returning it, so he won't be able to get a hold of it later to "make mistakes with".

Comment: Also a Stopwatch isn't doing any work or eating cpu clock cycles between the calls to Start() and Stop(). Start() just sets a timestamp to now and Stop() calculates and saves the time elapsed since that.

See source in coreclr:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Diagnostics/Stopwatch.cs/#L72

Comment: I think, from design perspective, would be better to write `using var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` instead of call `.Start()` and then `.Stop` and handle exceptions in the middle :)

Comment: @JobaDiniz Stopwatch isn't an IDisposable.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I think Tim's comment is more general. Sure in OP's case it is irrelevant, but in general it is good practice to wrap begin and end statements. Imagine Stopwatch reference being shared. Also see vvv's answer.

Comment: Exactly @nawfal, and that’s my point 

Answer (score 78):

No, there is no need to stop or clean it up.

`Stopwatch` does not use any unmanaged resources (if you thought of `IDisposable`). It actually does not use *any* resources at all (except the memory used by the object itself, of course)! It also does not consume any CPU while measuring the elapsed time!

In windows implementations of .NET (full .NET Framework, Mono, .NET Core), it just calls the [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904) Windows API when needed (on `Start()` and `Stop()` and when reading `Elapsed`) to retrieve a high resolution time stamp.

In Linux implementations of Mono and .NET Core, it uses [`clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) function to retrieve a monotonic increasing time value.

To anyone with a real curiosity about the implementation details: read [this post](https://aakinshin.net/blog/post/stopwatch).

Answer (score 4):

I think Stop is useful if you want to reuse the Elapsed value.

Comment: But I don't need in my example :)

Comment: Then it's great :), I should have used "only"
The class doesn't implement Dispose interface, so no cleanup should be trigger.

Comment: @vvv If you want you can add that to your answer - there's a button between the answer and the comments that says "edit".

Answer (score -2):

If your code doesn't need to calculate, then no need to use Stop().